# Do we have to add any configuration in openfire or modify hazelcast plugin to avoid this exception "HazelcastSerializationException"

Tags: java, serialization, openfire, classcastexception, hazelcast

Stack trace : 
SEVERE: [172.31.37.7]:5701 [openfire] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory$CallableTask
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCacheFactory$CallableTask
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:190)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:40)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:276)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:431)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.BaseCallableTaskOperation.readInternal(BaseCallableTaskOperation.java:91)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.readData(Operation.java:295)

Comment: Have you tried asking at igniterealtime.org, the site for Openfire?

Comment: Yes, I have posted it there too. I thought someone else might have worked on this openfire and hazelcast plugin and may be he can see it here.

Comment: I am seeing the same when I try to connect to an external Hazelcast instance.  The default for the Hazelcast plugin is to start local embedded HC instances which will communicate with each other.  Has anyone figured out how to make it work with an external instance?